# configure mod_rewrite on localhost windows xampp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am trying to get mod_rewrite to work on localhost.  If I go to localhost/website it loads the

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

and

```
localhost/website/home
```

also works

but for every other page it only shows the home page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^home/?$    home.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^about/?$    about.php    [NC,L]  <--- this goes to home
```

http.cfg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/website"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/website">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: What is exact URL you're entering in browser and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: localhost/website/about and the htaccess is located in the C:/xampp/htdocs/website folder

Comment: You need to use this URL: `http://locahost/about`

Comment: Ok thats working, so if I wanted to use localhost/website/about would I need to change ServerName to localhost/website ?

Comment: For that you need to change `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory...>`